# Floorheating: which material for the floor saves warmth at best?

Tags: floorheating

Is it some sort of wood? Or maybe tereacotta?

Comment: Much more info is needed. How is the warmth getting into the floor ? Please add a detailed description of why you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for something with “thermal mass”.

I’d use tile, concrete or rock material. All can absorb heat and then release the stored heat later. Here’s a website that explains it:

https://greenpassivesolar.com/passive-solar/building-characteristics/thermal-mass/

Answer (score 0):

Things with high heat capacity work best. So, tile. If your taking about hydronic floor heating, then concrete with whatever finishing material on that. More details are required to actually give you an answer but wood is generally a good insulation when talking about floor heat.